# Ocaml type error confusion: why is this making an error?

Tags: list, types, ocaml, typechecking

```
    let rec add_tail l e = match l with
      | [] -> [e]
      | (h::t) -> h::(add_tail t e)

    let rec fill_help l x n = match n = 0 with
      true -> l
      | false -> add_tail(l, x); fill_help(l, x, n-1)

    let fill x n = 
      let l = [] in
      fill_help(l, x, n)
```

and I'm getting the error in the interpreter

```
    # #use "prac.ml";;
    val prod : int list -> int = <fun>
    val add_tail : 'a list -> 'a -> 'a list = <fun>
    File "prac.ml", line 13, characters 21-27:
    Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
           but an expression was expected of type 'c list
```

line 13 would be

```
    | false -> add_tail(l, x); fill_help(l, x, n-1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you call `fill_help` with a tuple as an argument (`(l, x, n-1)`) even though it's not defined to take one. You should call `fill_help` as `fill_help l x (n-1)` instead. Same for `add_tail`.

Secondly you call a side-effect-free function (`add_tail`) and throw away its return value. This is almost always an error. It looks like you expect `l` to be different after the call to `add_tail`. It won't be. You probably want `fill_help (add_tail l x) x (n-1)`.

Comment: oh, i see. thanks so much. i'm so new and confused to ocaml syntax.